# Dynamically generated links to modals are being initialized upon each new generated link

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize

I am having an issue with a dynamically generated list that contains links to modals.  I have a list of cards (from materialize css) that contain information for various workouts.  The user has the option to add the workout to a list to create a workout routine.  When the workout is added to the list, a link to a modal is generated which contains information to the workout as well as an instructional video.  It appears that the way I have my code set up, each time a new workout is added to the list, the modal is triggered, making it so that any previously existing links are triggered again.  So if three workouts are present on the list, the first thing appended to that list has been initialized three times.  I believe that this is a logic error but I am unsure how to fix it.

If you need any more info or clarification about this please let me know.  Here is the relevant code.

```
    $(".add-workout").on("click", function(){
    var workoutExerciseIdForList = $(this).prev().attr("id");
    console.log(workoutExerciseIdForList);
    workoutListAppend(workoutExerciseIdForList);
  });

  //Append all necessary elements to workout list

  function workoutListAppend(workoutExerciseIdForList){
    var workoutName = workoutInfo[workoutExerciseIdForList][0].exercise;
    var workoutNameLink = $("<a>").attr("href","#modal-more-info").attr("id","name-"+workoutExerciseIdForList).addClass("modal-trigger").append(workoutName);
    var workoutAppend = $("<td>").append(workoutNameLink);
    var repAppend = $("<td>").append('<div class="input-field"><input class="formReps" id="reps-'+workoutExerciseIdForList+'" type="text" class="validate"><label for="reps-'+workoutExerciseIdForList+'"></label></div>');
    var setAppend = $("<td>").append('<div class="input-field"><input id="sets-'+workoutExerciseIdForList+'" type="text" class="validate"><label for="sets-'+workoutExerciseIdForList+'"></label></div>');
    var weightAppend = $("<td>").append('<div class="input-field"><input id="weight-'+workoutExerciseIdForList+'" type="text" class="validate"><label for="weight-'+workoutExerciseIdForList+'"></label></div>');
    var completeButtonAppend = $("<td>").append('<input type="checkbox" class="workoutCheckbox" id='+workoutExerciseIdForList+'-checkbox /><label for='+workoutExerciseIdForList+'-checkbox></label>');
    var removeWorkoutButton = $("<td>").append('<a class="waves-effect waves-light red btn">X</a>');
    var workoutAppendToTr = $("<tr>").append(workoutAppend)
                                     .append(repAppend)
                                     .append(setAppend)
                                     .append(weightAppend)
                                     .append(completeButtonAppend)
                                     .append(removeWorkoutButton);
    $("#workout-append").append(workoutAppendToTr);

    $('.modal-trigger').leanModal({
      dismissible: true, // Modal can be dismissed by clicking outside of the modal
      complete: function() { modalReset(); } // Callback for Modal close
    });

    enterToSubmitReps(workoutExerciseIdForList, workoutName);
    enterToSubmitSets(workoutExerciseIdForList, workoutName);
    enterToSubmitWeight(workoutExerciseIdForList, workoutName);
    fieldIsEmpty(workoutExerciseIdForList, workoutName);
    modalGetId(workoutExerciseIdForList);
    removeWorkoutHandler();
  };
```

When a button with the class add-workout is clicked, it gets the ID of the workout from an HTML element, which then retrieves data from a javascript object that I made, then runs the function workoutListAppend.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I'm assuming your issue is, or is stemming from, this block...

```
$('.modal-trigger').leanModal({
  dismissible: true, // Modal can be dismissed by clicking outside of the modal
  complete: function() { modalReset(); } // Callback for Modal close
});
```

Your finding all modal-trigger on the page and applying leanModal to them.  That means your doing that to all the previously existing ones as well and possibly double/triple binding events.  You need to do so only on the newly created elements.

```
workoutAppendToTr.find('.modal-trigger').leanModal({ ...
```

The above finds elements with the modal-trigger class, but only within workoutAppendToTr, which is your new elements.  So it only does the binding on the new things, rather than all the modal-triggers again.

Comment: thanks a lot that worked! would you mind explaining how it works?